# Founders of Cnidarian colony

Tags: zoology, reproduction

I know that colonial Cnidaria enlarge their colony by the means of asexual reproduction and sexual and asexual reproduction can originate individuals that will be part of other colonies.

Nevertheless, I cannot find any precise information about whether the individuals of a certain colony are all descendants of one founder or not. I thank you anybody for any answer!